# Defining bezier control points in relatively defined line rather than coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, bezier

Found it hard to write the title, I hope it makes sense.

We can define control points in bezier curves with `\draw (0,0) .. controls (0.5,0.5) .. (0,1);`

and we can define a drawn line differently from using two coordinates with `\draw (0,0) --++ (90:1);`.

But is there a way of combining the two? Something like `\draw (0,0) .. controls (0.5,0.5) .. --++ (90:1);`?

Comment: The "curve to" operation (`.. controls (coord) ..`) should _replace_ the "line to" operation (`--`) instead of being used simultaneously. That is, you want `\draw (0,0) .. controls (0.5,0.5) .. ++ (90:1);`

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. If you want to post it as an answer I can accept it?

Comment: @Emma You should make this an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "curve to" operation (.. controls (coord) ..) should replace the "line to" operation (--) instead of being used simultaneously. That is, you want

```
\draw (0,0) .. controls (0.5,0.5) .. ++ (90:1);
```